# sequelize hex column values auto conversion to buffer

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a mssql database with Id in the form of hex values.

For example, when viewed in Management studio, a typical id column looks like

```
id,                                  | userName
0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8ADEFF1C8246866,  | John
0xAF4845C8A34A48EF8B6D481F2D20D561,  | Peter
0x70B1F5E3B3F8417BBB99912640C54520,  | Alan
```

To query the user table, I need to write something like

```
SELECT * FROM users Where Id = 0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8ADEFF1C8246866
```

I use a lot of `sequelize.query` to run a bunch of SQL statements directly.

When such table is read in sequelize, the id gets converted into `buffer` type in sequelize. So my question is, how can I keep this hex value? Is there a config that keep the string hex value of these ids? Did I have to convert these buffer type manually to hex string by hand, and attach a `0x` in the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, when viewed in Management studio, a typical id column looks like

For me, a typical ID does not look like this, but I'm quite sure, that your hex-values are `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`s (=GUID) actually (see option 2).

### Option 1: HEX-string

You might store the hex string as its string representation:

```
SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexstr(0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8ADEFF1C8246866)
```

returns "0x8189cf203dea4a44b8adeff1c8246866" (which is a string now)

But - how ever - the function meant to do the opposite truncates part of this

```
select sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(N'0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8ADEFF1C8246866')
```

returns 0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8AD (which is to short!!!)

### OPTION 2: GUID

I would cast these values to GUIDs (if none of them is wider than 16 Bytes!) and store them typesafe. It is easy and fully *out-of-the-box* to get a GUID as its string representation (e.g. to write this in XML) and to cast it back to GUID.

```
SELECT CAST(0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8ADEFF1C8246866 AS uniqueidentifier);
```

returns 20CF8981-EA3D-444A-B8AD-EFF1C8246866

```
SELECT CAST('20CF8981-EA3D-444A-B8AD-EFF1C8246866' AS uniqueidentifier)
```

returns the same as above, just to show, that this string value is casted to a *real GUID*

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('20CF8981-EA3D-444A-B8AD-EFF1C8246866' AS uniqueidentifier) AS varbinary(max))
```

returns 0x8189CF203DEA4A44B8ADEFF1C8246866

Now you have your original HEX-string back again.

Comment: Ok.. this works. Will accept it if no better answer comes up. What I decided to do is to convert the buffer manually into "0x" + id.toString("hex") in my javascript code and pass that as Id around.

Comment: @user1017674 This depends on the amount of data and the operations you are going to perform. Just imagine an *ID-based* `JOIN` between millions of rows. The comparison of `GUID` is implemented in a high performance way. GUID takes 16 byte, a standard modern 64 bit PC can shuffle this in two goes... Strings are normally referenced with a memory address (extra operation) and you need 32 byte (in your case even 34 bytes) to compare. Adding the `0x` adds no extravalue, this will just make your strings larger and the first two characters are always the same... Would not be my choice...

Comment: Oh actually, I think your first option is exactly what I did in javascript. In that case, I will not do anything special handling in my javascript code in the web server and I should just use sys.fn_varbintohexstr() to read these weird IDs into an hex string. Thanks a lot!